# TypeScript global.d.ts module declaration is overriding entire @mui/material module when trying to fix theming issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, .d.ts

This issue stems from trying to set the `main` property on MUIs palette (`themeConfig.palette.primary.main = brandColor`).   This produces the following error:

```
Property 'main' does not exist on type 'PaletteColorOptions'.
Property 'main' does not exist on type 'Partial<Color>'.
```

I understand why this is happening:  `theme` is of type `ThemeOptions`, and going down the chain, [MUI defines primary](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createPalette.d.ts#L40) either as `SimplePaletteColorOptions | ColorPartial`, and `ColorPartial` does not have a property called `main`.

In order to try to resolve this, i created a `global.d.ts` file at the root of my `src` folder, and added the following code to augment the @mui/material module and add the missing property:

**global.d.ts**

```
 declare module '@mui/material' {
   interface Color {
     main?: string;
   }
 }
```

Doing this resolves the error, but produces errors on every line where I am importing from @mui/material, for example:

`Module '"@mui/material"' has no exported member 'ThemeOptions'.`

So it seems like the global.d.ts file is overwriting the module instead of augmenting/extending it?

I also have tried moving the module declaration to inside of the theme file (but after @mui/material imports) and that seems to resolve it entirely, but I don't know why.  It feels like a cleaner approach would be having the declaration inside of the `global.d.ts` file.